# Insert time-only into sql-server with php

Tags: php, sql-server

How can i insert time only into SQLSRV with php

at the moment i've 2 variable that received form javascript function

```
 $date = $_POST['date'];//datevariable = x/xx/xxxx > string 
 $time = $_POST['time'];//timevariable = xx:xx > string
```

and my table is

```
dates = date
times = time(7)
```

and i've get an error while i've try to insert into database
it said wrong datatype

so what's right datatype date/time format for my table?

or any other way to get current time/date to insert into the table ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or any other way to get current time/date to insert into the table ?

You can use the SQL Server GETDATE() function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytimetable] (
[d] [date] NULL
,[t] [time](7) NULL
)

DECLARE @now DATETIME = getdate()

INSERT INTO mytimetable (
    d
    ,t
    )
VALUES (
    @now
    ,@now
    )

SELECT *
FROM mytimetable

d          t
---------- ----------------
2015-08-09 22:46:07.0470000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: so these mean i need to query 2 time with php to insert 1 row ?

Comment: no, you can just use getdate() where @now is used in the inserts, Nick is trying to illustrate, but if doing many inserts using a local variable will hold the same datetime value for all the inserts. make sense now